# LayoutManager with dynamic column count

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I currently have this RecyclerView in Android:

[image: What I have]

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I am trying to reproduce this layout:

[image: What I try to reproduce]

A list of cities (tiles of different width) in a vertical RecyclerView. I would like the tiles to be left aligned and go on new line only when there is no free space for the next one.

I don't know how to create a custom LayoutManager for my needs.
All help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [ChipsLayoutManager](https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager) is what you are looking for.